# Is there another way to state summations like this

Tags: polynomials, nonlinear-system

I have a product looking like this:

$$\omega = (aP+bQ+ \cdots)(cP+dQ+ \cdots)(eP+fQ+ \cdots)(gP+hQ+ \cdots)$$

So terms like $P,Q,R$, and so on repeat in every parentheses here, with different variable coefficients each time. I hope that makes sense.

Is there another way to write an expression like this, possibly in terms of $P,Q$? Is it a well known type of equation?

Edit - maybe clearer if I write general form:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}  \sum_{j=1}^{m} x_{ij} y_j$$

$n$ is the number of products (the example I have above is $n=4$) and $m$ is the number of terms in each product.

Comment: Your last format with the product symbol over the sum seems general enough, however I don't know a typical *name* for this kind of product of sums. Not to say there isn't such a name...

Comment: @coffeemath Does the expansion of this summation allow for easy transformation into another type of summation?

Comment: I think if expanded there would be a lot of terms and it could,  if one wanted to, be expressed as a sum of the multiplied out terms where "like terms" involving the products of the $y_j$ with the coefficients of each product in terms of the $x_{ij}$. But this would get messy in general, so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of (in this generality) is the following :

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mx_{i,j}y_j=\sum_{(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m)\mid \alpha_1+...+\alpha_m=n}X_{\overline{\alpha}}y_1^{\alpha_1}...y_m^{\alpha_m} $$

Where $\overline{\alpha}$ stands for $(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ and :

$$X_{\overline{\alpha}}:=\sum_{(A_1,...,A_n)\text{ partitions of }\{1,...,m\}\text{ with } |A_i|=\alpha_i\text{ for all } i}\prod_{j=1}^mw_j(A_1,...,A_n) $$

Where $w_j(A_1,...,A_n)=x_{i,j}$ where $i$ is the unique index such that $j\in A_i$.

Clearly the formula is nasty, however it may be interesting in some cases (maybe)...